# Apache VFS - setPreferredAuthentications - What is the possible values for

Tags: java, apache-vfs

I was looking into using VFS for *sftp* a file in Java. In the following documentation for [setPreferredAuthentications](https://home.apache.org/%7Eelserj/commons/commons-vfs-2.1/commons-vfs2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/vfs2/provider/sftp/SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.html#setPreferredAuthentications(org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemOptions,%20java.lang.String)) it mentions preferredAuthentications - The authentication order - What are the possible values? Was unable to find an answer on-line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `setPreferredAuthentications` is equivalent to `SSH` config option `PreferredAuthentications`, it specifies the order in which the client should try authentication methods.

**Possible values are list of ssh authentication methods:**

```java
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance()
    .setPreferredAuthentications(opts,"gssapi-with-mic,hostbased,publickey");

//or
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance()
    .setPreferredAuthentications(opts,"password,keyboard-interactive");
```

**OpenSSH perspective:**

As detailed in [OpenSSH Manual](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#AUTHENTICATION):

> The methods available for authentication are: GSSAPI-based authentication, host-based authentication, public key authentication, challenge-response authentication, and password authentication. Authentication methods are tried in the order specified above, though `PreferredAuthentications` can be used to change the default order.

This allows a client to prefer one method (e.g. keyboard-interactive) over another method (e.g. password).

For example :
`gssapi-with-mic,hostbased,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password`

The available authentication methods of OpenSSH are:

- `gssapi-with-mic`
- `hostbased`
- `keyboard-interactive`
- `none` (used for access to password-less accounts when Cm PermitEmptyPassword is enabled)
- `password`
- `publickey`

**Apache VSF perspective:**

The Apache VFS project uses [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library as an underlayer sftp provider, you can find the detailed config options of jsch [in its api doc here](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/simple.javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setConfig-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

> User Authentication methods (UserAuth)
>
> Here the user sends a list of methods, and we have a list of methods in the option PreferredAuthentications (in preference order). We take the first of our methods which is supported by the server, get the userauth.method variable to load the implementing class, and try to authenticate. This will repeat until we are authenticated or no more methods left.
>
> The following ones are built in:
>
> `userauth.none`
> mainly for getting the list of methods the server supports.
> `userauth.password`
> usual password authentication.
>
> `userauth.keyboard-interactive`
> Using the generic message exchange authentication mechanism, as defined in RFC 4256.
>
> `userauth.publickey`
> public key authentication, using an Identity.
>
> `userauth.gssapi-with-mic`
> Using the GSS-API (see below) as defined in RFC 4462, section 3.
> For the GSS-API mechanism we need an implementation of GSSContext to refer to, which will be chosen by the configuration option gssapi-with-mic.method, the method being chosen from a list given by the server. For now, we (hardcoded) only support the krb5 method, resulting in:
>
> `gssapi-with-mic.krb5`
> Kerberos 5 authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Mm, that is most likely related to SSH authentication. You might use "publickey,password" to prefer public key authentication as the string parameter in your directive.

Maybe this answer will also give you more clues:

https://serverfault.com/q/986839

and a documentation page for OpenSSH client:

https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#PreferredAuthentications